# Why Admob Library not syncing?

Tags: android, gradle, admob

My admob library is not syncing in android studio version 3.2.1 and admob library version 17.1.1. After syncing
dependency  (`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'`)
then my (`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`) is showing error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you dependency version seems to be `17.1.2` instead of `17.1.1`.

If again the error occurs, the mistake could be you forgot to add the following code to your project level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Hope this resolves the AdMob dependency error.

Now for the support library, I too have such errors in my apps and I do one thing to remove this. Just migrate to `AndroidX`.

To do so, go to **Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX** option in Android Studio menu bar.